# Minimum and maximum 10 numbers from given n numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, max, minimum

Can you suggest an efficient algorithm to find the minimum 10 and maximum 10 numbers from a set of given n numbers(unsorted) ?

One way I thought of will be to sort the array and then pick.

There should be a better way to do it.

Can you suggest an approach?

This isn't a homework question.

Comment: @Claudiu Technically I think that only partial sorting algorithms can be used by OP. The link covers it, but selection only deals with `k-th` largest number, not getting `top-k` items. Although the former can be reduced to the latter, I am not sure if the other way around is possible with out giving up the complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python standard library has this worked-out already (heapq.nlargest and heapq.smallest).

For your case, it would work out to making a min-heap and a max-heap prepopulated with the first 10 members of your dataset, then make a single pass over the data, updating the heaps as necessary:

```
FOR element IN remaining_data
    IF element > top_of_min_heap
    THEN update_min_heap(element)
    ENDIF

    IF element < top_of_max_heap
    THEN update_max_heap(element)
    ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

The *update* step replaces the existing smallest-of-the-ten-largest-already-seen and the largest-of-the-ten-smallest-already-seen.

Here is roughly what the Python standard library code looks like:

```
def nlargest(n, iterable):
    """Find the n largest elements in a dataset.                                                                                 

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, reverse=True)[:n]                                                                           
    """
    if n < 0:
        return []
    it = iter(iterable)
    result = list(islice(it, n))      # pre-populate with the first n elements
    if not result:
        return result
    heapify(result)                   # arrange them into a minheap
    for elem in it:                  
        if element > result[0]:       # new elem is bigger than the smallest-of-the-large
            heapreplace(result, elem) # replace top element with new element
    result.sort()                     # sort the top ten
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Make two heaps of size `k` (`k=10`), one with `less` as comparer and second with `more`. Two have two structures that will store "top k" elements.

Go over every element and put into each heap. If the elements go out of heap, forget them, it means they are not in top 10.

I believe this is a variation of something called Hadian-Sobel algorithm. It's a base for heap sort. Kind of like partition (Hoare algorithm I believe) for quick-sort. Which also could be used here btw.

This way you get `O(n) * 2 O(log k)`. `N` elements times two `heap_insert` of size `k`. This is `O(n log k)` which is basically linear for `k=10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quick select algorithm explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to find the kth largest number from an unsorted array of integers. After that you can iterate the array one more time and check for elements which are larger than kth largest element. So in two iterations you can find top k elements. Similarly you can apply this approach to find smallest k elements.

Time complexity of selection ranking algorithm is O(n) in average case, where n is number of elements in the array. Traversing the array second time also takes O(n) time. Thus overall complexity will also be O(n).

This algorithm will run faster than the approach which uses heaps. Because using that approach time complexity will be O(nlogk).

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking too much, you just need to scan the array once and fill it to two arrays tracking 10 minimum values and 10 maximum values by commparing to the largest minimum and lowest maximum. O(n)

A sort has O(n log n)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java You can use Treemap http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html.

The order of the keys can be sorted, and when iterating over the keys, you can expect that they will be in order.

Time complexity for this is O(n)

Comment: The suggested algorithm being what?